# Removing 'Kubuntu-desktop' has made media keys practically non-responsive but only on Unity Desktop

Tags: unity, gnome, kubuntu, kde

After uninstalling the package 'Kubuntu-desktop' my media keys no longer work, but only specifically in the Unity Desktop. They work flawlessly in Gnome, Enlightenment and KDE but when used on the Unity desktop they take around two minutes to respond. It seems the uninstallation of Kubuntu-desktop has took with it whatever file is responsible for media keys, and as such I am now stranded.

I am running Ubuntu 18.10 on a Dell Inspiron 15 3000.

Comment: Kubuntu-desktop is a meta-package. When uninstalled it takes nothing with it. It is not the cause of the problem.

Comment: So if it was not Kubuntu then what could it be?

Comment: Your guess is as good as mine